# How to retrieve elements in particular namespace?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I use C#. Please consider following XML:

```
<item>
  <title>lorem</title>
  <description>ipsum</description>
  <media:category>Sports</media:category>
  <media:title>Combo</media:title>
  <media:thumbnail url='http://dolor/0.jpg' height='100' width='200'/>
  <media:thumbnail url='http://sit/0.jpg' height='300' width='400'/>
</item>
```

I would like to be able to retrieve a List of all elements that have namespace eg. `media`.
The XML is loaded into `XElement`. I am able to find elements using Linq by name, eg. `thumbnail`, but not by namespace.

This is not always a valid XML, because `xmlns` namespace is not always declared. It is loaded to XElement this way:

```
XElement _root = XDocument.Parse(xmlString).Root;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this XPath expression to select all element in specific namespace :

```
//*[namespace-uri()='http://uri-address-here']
```

For example in C# :

```
var xml = @"<item xmlns:media='http://www.foo.org/'>
  <title>lorem</title>
  <description>ipsum</description>
  <media:category>Sports</media:category>
  <media:title>Combo</media:title>
  <media:thumbnail url='http://dolor/0.jpg' height='100' width='200'/>
  <media:thumbnail url='http://sit/0.jpg' height='300' width='400'/>
</item>";
var element = XElement.Parse(xml);
var elements = element.XPathSelectElements("//*[namespace-uri()='http://www.foo.org/']");
```

Comment: But my root tag does not have `xmlns:media='http://www.foo.org/'`. Can  I somehow select elements anyway?

Comment: then it isn't valid XML. `XElement.Parse(xml)` throws exception if `media` prefix is not declared

Comment: It was loaded this way: `XDocument.Parse(xmlString).Root` - did not throw exception and returned `XElement`.

Comment: `xmlns:media='http://some-url'` must be declared somewhere in the XML (maybe at root element). Not necessarily at `<item>` element. It should work just fine as long as namespace declaration exist